# Passing part structure between C++ and C#

Tags: c#, c++, parameter-passing

In C++ I have structure like this:

```
struct Structure
{
    std::vector<int> vect;
    int i;
    double d;
};
```

but in C# I don't need this vector. Is it a way to pass part of this structure to C#?

I try to do something like this:

```
[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct Structure
{
    public int i;
    public double d;
}
```

but it isn't working.

Comment: It *may* work if you stick the vector at the end of the struct and then the int and double will align.

Comment: I would just copy the int and the double components out into another struct, and pass that instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot arbitrarily chop off parts at the top or in the middle of the `struct` and expect it to work, because offsets of the members that you pass will be different.

```
----------- ------------
| C++ view | C# view   |
----------- ------------
|   vect   |     i     |
----------- ------------
|     i    |     d     |
----------- ------------
|     d   |
----------
```

Your trick may work, however, if you move the vector to the bottom of your `struct`: you should be able to pass individual `struct`s, but not arrays of them.

```
----------- ------------
| C++ view | C# view   |
----------- ------------
|     i    |     i     |
----------- ------------
|     d    |     d     |
----------- ------------
|   vect   |
----------
```

It also wouldn't work if `Structure` is used as a member of a larger `struct`.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to work, since the `vect` field is missing from the .Net stucture. Try to add a field to the .Net struct with the exact same size as `vect`: `sizeof(vect)`.